# CSS ignore parent elements of same the type

Tags: html, css, web

I need to add styles to an HTML code element that has duplicate parent elements of the same type.

Example: 
`<code><code><code>foo</code></code></code>`

I only want to apply styles to one of the elements, for example `code { padding: 1px; }` actually results in 3px in this example.

I have no control of this HTML as it is generated, it also can have only one parent code element sometimes.

Is it possible to write a CSS rule that ignores the parent elements and only targets the one?

Comment: You can use the `>` operator to refer to direct children.

Comment: you want it for the first or the third

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you know the number of nested levels

You can use the child combinator `>` if you know the depth of the nested element.

The `>` selector 'matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the children of elements matched by the first'.

```css
code > code > code {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<code><code><code>foo</code></code></code>
```

### If you don't know the number of nested levels

The only option that currently works is to target the top-level `code` element for styling, then remove the styling from any nested `code` elements.

```css
code {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px;
}

code code {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<code>foo</code>

<code><code>foo</code></code>

<code><code><code>foo</code></code></code>

<code><code><code><code>foo</code></code></code></code>
```

### In the future

Once CSS Selectors Level 4 is implemented you'll be able to use the `:has` pseudo-class, like:

```
code:not(:has(> code))
```

Example (which won't work in any browser at this point):

```css
code:not(:has(> code))  {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<code><code>foo</code></code>

<code><code><code>foo</code></code></code>
```

Comment: In his **question** he has clearly said that - *I have no control of this HTML as it is generated, it also can have only one parent code element sometimes.* so this method will not work.

Comment: @weBer saw that after I answered and updated my solution

Comment: Your first answer was not the right solution that why I commented, but now it's looking much better. now its better than my answer :)

Comment: The solution of targeting the top element worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

As per you **Question**(*I have no control of this HTML as it is generated, it also can have only one parent code element sometimes.*)

we can use use the selector `>` to remove the style for the `<code>` tag and apply padding to only the first `<code>` only. Check the demo, I hope it was helpful, and by the way, **there is no way to write a CSS rule that ignores the parent elements and only targets the one so have to use workarounds like this.**

```css
code {
  padding: 1px
}

code>code {
  padding: 0px
}

code>code>code {
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<code>
 <code>
  <code>foo</code>
 </code>
</code>

<code>
 <code>foo</code>
</code>

<code>foo</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the depth of your `code` tags:

```
code > code > code {
   padding: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector ">" as here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

In your example would be something like this:

```
code > code > code{
    padding:1px;
}
```